# Installing pip on windows?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I tried to install pip on windows i.e

```
C:\Python34>python get-pip.py
```

also i set the path for python but it gives an message i.e.

```
python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

so what can i do for installing pip?please anyone help me?

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip

Comment: Are you sure that get-pip.py is in the Python34 folder ?

Answer (score 1):

You can install pip installer from windows command prompt 
first download the **get-pip.py** from the internet from this site https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py then run the file from command prompt

```
python get-pip.py
```

This will download and install the pip installer into your machine
to use it use the following command

```
pip install <package_name>
```

or if that doesn't work use;

```
python -m pip install <package_name>
```

or you can use this;

```
py -3 -m pip install <package_name>
```

To update pip use the following command;

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with pip if you you select the option. If you did, just upgrade it.

If you are unsure of the instruction go to [this link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) which is the official pip website. Make sure that your environment variables has the scripts folder and python folder in PATH.