# How to install python packages from CMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to install urllib2 and JSON but it doesn't seem to let me. I tried using pip install in cmd which didn't work and also tried specifying the Scripts path and then doing the command but that does not work either. I am on 64-bit and I have used some command in pip like pip install python3 (package name) which worked for me but I haven't install anything in some time so I don't remember what the command was exactly that worked for me.

Comment: *"I tried using pip install in cmd which didn't work"* - well, the answer is to use pip install, so if you don't tell us specifically what you mean by "didn't work" then we can't help you. What operating system/shell are you using, what exact command did you enter, and what was the error message?

Comment: I typed this command (pip install urllib2) in CMD first and then after I specified my python Scripts directory. My operating system is Windows 10 64-bit and I'm using CMD or Command Prompt.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the command `pip install (package name)`?
You can also try to upgrade pip to the latest version with `pip install --upgrade pip` and then install a package.

EDIT: 
`Please note that The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error`. There is no need to install urllib2. Just import urllib.request into your script

Comment: yes that's the exact command i tried and I also upgraded my pip to the latest version and tried but this did not work either.

Comment: Please note that `The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error`. There is no need to install urllib2. Just import urllib.request into your script

Answer (score 0):

Both of those should be apart of the standard library so there shouldn't be a need to reinstall using pip. Try reinstalling python3 (uninstall then reinstall) and check the "add to path" button at the bottom of the installer before installation.

Comment: Confirm your path variables are pointing to the correct directory. Also, try using the IDLE editor and import json and urllib3 while in interpreted mode. You will know it worked if there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `pip3 install (package name)` and also try to update it to the latest version using simocat's answer

Edit: I believe you don't need to install these packages they come as part of python 3.x

Comment: yes that's the exact command i tried and I also upgraded my pip to the latest version and tried but this did not work either.

Comment: and I think i do because whenever I run them on any IDLE it says no module of that name can be found

Comment: See my edit: no need to install these, just import json in your code should work. If not I would suggest uninstalling python 3 and reinstall

Comment: yes, the import JSON works fine because that's a module that comes with python when you install but urllib2 is a module that doesn't and therefore I have to install it on my own.

Comment: for json this comes with python. I tried on pycharm 2020.1 and it worked. For urlib2 I am using urlib3 (which requires a pip install), need to check urlib2

Comment: ^ read my comment above JSON works but urllib2 doesn't come when you install Python so I have to install separately.

Comment: For urllib2 maybe that would help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2

Answer (score 0):

What does:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

in cmd respond?

(It is always helpful to post the Error output you receive from your commandline) and on these kinds of topics in general you may check: https://stackexchange.com/

Btw. Here is a related q&a:
[Installing pip on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840653/installing-pip-on-windows)